# need to create a userdefualt that saves a double as a high score (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, save, nsuserdefaults

I would like the label foxmill to store a high score using a user default. Obviously if there is a new high score I would like it to be replaced. The problem is that totalTime (what tracks the score) is a double and not a int. All of the tutorials use a int for the high score tutorial.

```
    import UIKit
class winViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var score2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var winningLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet var foxMill: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet var hhighscore: UILabel!
    public var LebelText: String?
    public var LebelText2: String?
    public var LebelText3: String?
    public var LebelText4: String?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
                timeCalculation()
     loadState()



           }
    func saveScore(score: Double) {

        // Instantiate user defaults
        let userDefaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        // Set your score
        userDefaults.set(score, forKey: "highScore")

        // Sync user defaults
        userDefaults.synchronize()

    }

    func loadState() {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let score = userDefaults.double(forKey: "highScore")
        foxMill.text = "High Score: \(score)"
    }
            func timeCalculation(){

        guard let unwrapedText = self.LebelText2 else {
            return
        }

        guard let unwrapedText2 = self.LebelText else {
                return
        }
        guard let unwrapedText3 = self.LebelText3 else {
            return
        }
        guard let unwrapedText4 = self.LebelText4 else {
            return
        }

        if let myInt = Double(unwrapedText),  let myInt2 = Double(unwrapedText2), let myInt3 = Double(unwrapedText3), let myInt4 = Double(unwrapedText4)


        {
            var  totalTime = myInt + myInt2 + myInt3 + myInt4
            self.winningLabel.text = "You won"+"\n"+"Reaction time :" + String(totalTime) + " Seconds"
             saveScore(score: totalTime)

                }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just save the value with the proper key, then when you retrieve it, make sure to do so as a `Double`:

```
 func saveScore(score: Double) {

     // Instantiate user defaults
     let userDefaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

     // Set your score
     userDefaults.set(score, forKey: "highScore")

     // Sync user defaults
     userDefaults.synchronize()

}
```

Now when you update your score values, when you say ... (`unwrappedText`), to make sure you save the user defaults

```
if let myInt = Double(unwrapedText),  let myInt2 = Double(unwrapedText2), let myInt3 = Double(unwrapedText3), let myInt4 = Double(unwrapedText4)

    // HERE you do whatever it was you originally did with the text, but also save a value

    saveScore(score: myInt)

{
```

Now the next time you load your app, to load the score:

```
func loadScore() {
     // Instantiate User Defaults
     let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
     let score = userDefaults.double(forKey: "highScore")
}
```

You really shouldn't name a property "myInt" when you want it to be a `Double` and not an `Integer`

If you want your `foxMill` label to display this high score at load, you want to do two things. First make sure before you app closes at some point you save your state by synchronizing your `UserDefaults`, look into methods like `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate` in your `AppDelegate` - but that's a little beyond the scope of your question. For now I'll assume you've properly saved your state last time the app quit by calling the `saveScore(score:)` function I listed above.  So now you want to retrieve the score and update your `foxMill` label at load. You would do something like this:

You could do something like this, by amending the `loadScore` method above:

```
func loadScore() {
     // Instantiate User Defaults
     let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
     let score = userDefaults.double(forKey: "highScore")
     foxMill.text = "High Score: \(score)"
}
```

And then at the end of `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadScore()
}
```

Or you could change the method to return a string which you would then assign to your label's text:

```
func loadScore() -> String {
     // Instantiate User Defaults
     let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
     let score = userDefaults.double(forKey: "highScore")
     return "High Score: \(score)"
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    foxMill.text = loadScore()
}
```

Comment: How would i use my label foxmill with this?

Comment: @joemax - I don't understand what you're asking. You want to save the high score as a `Double` using `User Defaults`, what does that have to do with your `UILabel`?

Comment: what would i put in viewdidload?

Comment: Do you want the `foxMill` label to just display this high score?

Comment: I will update my answer for what you're asking. If it works for you, please accept it as correct. Check back in a couple minutes.

Comment: It's worth noting that calling `synchronize` on NSUserDefaults is actively discouraged now, and will be deprecated in a future release.

Comment: @DaveLyon - What is the generally accepted method now? I apologize if I'm using obsolete code, I actually haven't used anything but CoreData in years, I just posted my answer based on what was used a couple years ago when I last used `UserDefaults`

Comment: @Pierce I don't know what to put in  userDefaults.set(myInt, forKey: "highScore") myInt or totalTime is not working.

Comment: @joemax - I'll edit it once more in a way that may help

Comment: @joemax look again, at the top of the answer I explain how to save

Comment: @Pierce this works but there is not way for the highest score to be saved. What the current time of the game is that is the high score. I would like the code to save the lowest of "totalTime". I edited my question with the current code.

Comment: @Pierce It's sad that the best link is an Apple engineer on Twitter, but at least as a primary source, there's this: https://twitter.com/catfish_man/status/674727133017587712

But, if you take a look at the Objective-C headers it gives a specific warning, and indicates how to avoid using it.